# PHP Custom Session Handler Behavior

Tags: php, session, handler, session-cookies

I'm having trouble getting my custom session handler to work between different page requests.  When a session is initially created the handler works as expected, however when I navigate to another page the session cookie and session ID remain the same, but the session data is deleted.

For example,

```
class NativeSessionHandler implements \SessionHandlerInterface
{
protected $rootDir = '/tmp';
protected $savePath;

public function open($savePath, $name)
{
    $this->savePath = $this->rootDir . '/' . $savePath;
    if (! is_dir($this->savePath)) {
        mkdir($this->savePath);
    }

    return true;
}

public function close()
{
    return true;
}

public function read($sessionId)
{
    $file = $this->savePath . $sessionId;
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        file_get_contents($file);
    }

    return true;
}

public function write($sessionId, $data)
{
    $file = $this->savePath . $sessionId;
    return file_put_contents($file, $data);
}

public function destroy($sessionId)
{
    $file = $this->savePath . $sessionId;
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }

    return true;
}

public function gc($maxlifetime)
{
    foreach (glob($this->savePath) as $file) {
        if (file_exists($file) && filemtime($file) + $maxlifetime < time()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    return true;
    }
}

// index.php
$handler = new NativeSessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($handler);

session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
echo session_id();
var_dump($_SESSION); // 'foo' => 'bar'

// page.php
$handler = new NativeSessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($handler);
session_start();
echo session_id(); // same session ID as on index.php
var_dump($_SESSION); // returns null
```

Any help figuring out how to get this working properly would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `write` or `read` methods of your session handler don't work. Try to fix it. You can set variable in $_SESSION and use it in the same page because PHP uses your session handler in the end of the script.

Comment: If you don't mind could you see if you notice anything in my handler?  When I open the /tmp directory it's actually writing data to the file but when I navigate to the other page it keeps the file but clears the data.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out.  You were correct that the read/write functions were broken.  I needed to serialize and unserialize the data when reading and writing.  Thanks for your help.

```
public function read($sessionId)
{
    $file = $this->savePath . $sessionId;
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $data = file_get_contents($file);
        return unserialize($data);
    }
}

public function write($sessionId, $data)
{
    $file = $this->savePath . $sessionId;
    return file_put_contents($file, serialize($data));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that was the reason? I have been [testing](https://gist.github.com/mindplay-dk/623bdd50c1b4c0553cd3) session handler behavior extensively, and `$data` given to `write()` is already serialized, as far as I can tell.